# Check if one String contains another String in Java

Tags: java

Is it possible to compare these 2 strings to give me true? does a union between contains and equals exist? thank you

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  
    String p0 = "HELLO WORLD";
    String p1 = "Hello - World";
  
    System.out.println(p0.contains(p1));
    System.out.println(p0.equals(p1));
  }
}
```

Comment: What are the rules here? If one string contains each word of the other string, case independently? `p0` is never going to contain `p1`, since there is one character, the hyphen, that is in `p1` but not in `p0`. But it would be possible to go the other direction, and check if each word in `p0` is in `p1`, case independently. Then `p1` would "contain" `p0`. Split on spaces, and try to find each word as a (quoted) regex in the other string, ignoring case.

Comment: i found the solution

Comment: It is definitely possible to compare these to with a method that will return true. “areEqual(s1, s2) { return true;}” will do the trick and return true for every set of inputs. If you have rules that can be followed to make it return true or false depending on the inputs then you’d have to code them into the method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
boolean result = p0.contains(p1);
```

this will give a true or false.

Comment: this returns false, i would like true

Comment: That's because "HELLO WORLD" and "Hello - World" are not the same. To return true,

Comment: in fact I'm asking if there is a way to get true back...

Comment: I have to rephrase that. .contains means that if one String let's say "Hello" contains another string "ello" it would return true because "ello" is in the string "Hello". Does that make sense?

Comment: If you want to get a return of true, change String p0 = "HELLO WORLD";
    String p1 = "Hello - World"; to  ```String p0 = "HELLO WORLD";    String p1 = "WORLD";```

Comment: i found the solution

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if a string `s1` contains all the words of another string `s2`,
since Java 8, you can do:

- If `s2` only has words:

  ```
  boolean s1ContainsS2 = Stream.of(s2.toUpperCase().split(" "))       // get words in uppercase
                               .allMatch(s1.toUpperCase()::contains); // check s1 contains all the words of s2
  ```
- If `s2` has other symbols/numbers that you want to ignore:

  ```
  boolean s1ContainsS2 = Stream.of(s2.toUpperCase().split(" "))        // get "words" in uppercase
                               .filter(word -> word.matches("[A-Z]+")) // ignore what is not a word
                               .allMatch(s1.toUpperCase()::contains);  // check the same than before
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to test the same sequence of letters you can do it like this.

```
String p0 = "HELLO WORLD";
String p1 = "Hello - World";
```

- `[^A-Za-z]` - match any non-letter.

```
System.out.println(p0.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]", "").toLowerCase()
          .contains(p1.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]", "").toLowerCase()));

System.out.println(p0.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]", "")
          .equalsIgnoreCase(p1.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]", "")));
```

In both cases they print true.  To facilitate this you could write a `BiPredicate`. Here is one for `equals`.

```
BiPredicate<String,String> areEqual = (a,b)-> a.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]", "")
              .equalsIgnoreCase(b.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]", ""));    
        
System.out.println(areEqual.test(p0,p1));
```

prints

```
true
```

Answer (score -2):

Whit this I succeeded:

```
    String p2 = p1.replaceAll(" - "," ");
    System.out.println(p0.equalsIgnoreCase(p2));
```

Comment: Use `String.replace()`  instead of `String.replaceAll()` if you don't use `regex`.